# how to enable and disable double click mouse options in kde

Tags: linux, command-line, kde, user-interface, dolphin-file-manager

I use dolphin as my default file browser. 
The recent releases have moved the options to configure single/double click open of files.

> Settings -> Configure Dolphin -> Navigation - Mouse

I find that I use double click to open as a single click to select allows me to manage my files a lot more easily.

How do I change these settings in the new version of dolphin?

I am using i3 windows manager on manjaro distro.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Start **System Settings** then type in the search box "double click" and ****select Workspace Behavior****

[image]

Then under **General Behavior** change the radio button from *Opens them* to *Selects them*

[image]

Comment: This is the current correct method. Everything else is either outdated or a workaround that doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Sadly, this is currently not working with dolphin 23.08.4 given by snap instead of apt (kubuntu 22.04.03)

Comment: With Plasma 6 changing the default, this question and answer got a lot more relevance.

Answer (score 10):

After weeks of trying different things.

### Using systemseting5

#### Option 1

I could not [follow these instructions](http://www.lostsaloon.com/technology/how-to-enable-and-disable-double-click-mouse-options-in-kde/). As they relate to an older version of dolphin and KDE.

> systemsettings from the command prompt -> Input Devices under the Hardware section ->  Mouse section in the left-hand side menu > Double-click to open files and folders

#### Option 2

I could not [follow these instructions](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=223&t=128669)
As my systemsettings5 did not have all the options available to set

> Under Workspace section > Desktop Behaviour > Workspace > Click behaviour > Single/Double Click Option

I didn't have `Desktop Behaviour` as an option. 
I fixed this by installing the missing package

```
sudo pacman -S plasma-meta
```

Then I could follow the above options.

### Alternatives command line

Change the options in the kdeglobals config of my user.

```
vim ~/.config/kdeglobals
...
[KDE]
...
SingleClick=false
...
```

Restart.

Comment: +1 for the config file location and field

Comment: [KDE]
...
SingleClick=false  Thanks, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this problem with your keyboard using

> `Ctrl+left click`

That will let you single click files to do file operations like move and copy etc.

Comment: My config is Manjaro / Arch is broken and I can't switch modes single / double click through the settings. :<.